# Show that $\sum (-1)^{j+1}b_j$ with $b_1=1,b_j=(4j-5)^{-1}+(4j-3)^{-1}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following question is from a homework assignment that is due today and I need to finish it (urgently). I managed to do (i) but I'm not sure how to do (ii). For (ii), I can see that $(s_{2k-1})$ is the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j + 1}b_j$ by observation (i.e. listing out a few terms), but I'm not sure how to formally show it. For (iii), I think the way to do it would be to observe that since $(s_{2k})$ and $(s_{2k - 1})$ partition $(s_n)$ and they converge to the same limit, then $(s_n)$ should be convergent, although I'm not 100% sure on this.

[image]

Comment: For (ii) do an inductive argument: check for $k=1$, then look at the difference $s_{2k+1}-s_{2k-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii), you want to prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j+1}b_j=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i-1}$$
This can be achieved with mathematical induction. For $n=1$ the result is true since
$$\sum_{j=1}^{1}(-1)^{j+1}b_j=b_1=1=\sum_{i=0}^{0}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{0}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{0}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i-1}\ .$$
Assume that the result holds for $n>1$ and let's see that it holds for $n+1$.

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{j+1}b_j=(-1)^{n+2}b_{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j+1}b_j$$ $$=(-1)^{n+2}b_{n+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i-1}$$ $$=(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{4(n+1)-5}+\frac{1}{4(n+1)-3}\right)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i-1}$$ $$=(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{4n-1}+\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i-1}$$  $$=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{4i-1} \ ,$$

So the identity follows.

Comment: For (iii), note that the difference $s_{2k}-s_{2k-1}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2(2k)-1}$. This implies that the desired series converges.